# hg convert from cvs broke branches

Tags: mercurial, branch, cvs, mercurial-convert

I converted an old cvs repository into mercurial via `hg convert`. Everything seemed to be okay (at least with the default branch) but all feature branches are missing files which haven't been changed in the branch. Is there any way to fix this up?

I'm using version 1.5, convert has been done via `hg convert cvs/checkout newrepo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably better off using cvs2svn to do the conversion, as it has a lot more "lore" built into it for weird corner cases. Then you can run hg convert on the resulting SVN repository. This is what the [Mercurial Wiki itself recommends](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryConversion#CVS) when things go wrong.

Comment: Convert from cvs to svn and then to hg did the trick. I also tried cvs2hg which did a not so great job as it created a bunch of strange commits.